# Add events to Viewing Application

Tags: autodesk-viewer

Is it possible to add event listeners to a viewing application?

I know it's possible to add them on a viewer object using the `addEventListener` method, but how can I add events to a viewing application?

CLARIFICATION:
I know I can use `this.viewerApp.getCurrentViewer()` to get the viewer and then use `addEventListener`, but is there a better or more correct way?

Comment: Could you share the use case why you want to add event listeners to `ViewerApplication` rather than `Viewer3D`?  `ViewerApplication` is just a utility class for creating a viewer instance as I know.

Comment: @EasonKang I was just wondering if I could add them to the `ViewingApplication`, but from your response and @Philippe's answer I see I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, `ViewingApplication` is just a wrapper around the `Viewer` object, so you need to add the event to viewer itself:

```
function onItemLoadSuccess(viewer, item) {
    viewer.addEventListener (...)
}

// or
var viewer = viewerApp.getCurrentViewer() //only after onItemLoadSuccess, viewer is not instanciated before
viewer.addEventListener (...)
```